# How can I pass variable to check plagiarism in Copyleaks API using PHP.? Here is my Code. I have just implement API in php code yet

Tags: php, copyleaks-api, github-third-party-apps

Following are my code that return expiry time of token and some other login info.

```
include_once('vendor/copyleaks/php-plagiarism-checker/autoload.php');
use Copyleaks\Copyleaks;
$copyleaks = new Copyleaks();
$loginResult = $copyleaks->login('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com','My-Api-Key Here');
echo json_encode($loginResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what are you trying to scan.

You can follow the example found at:

https://github.com/Copyleaks/PHP-Plagiarism-Checker/blob/master/demo/demo.php

and the Copyleaks API documentation:

https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3

Comment: I have already applied API. Now need to know how to pass data for pladgerism check.